# Show report formula grouping in dashboard metric

Tags: reporting, dashboard, report-formula

I'm trying to create a dashboard metric that shows the percentage of accounts we have business at in Texas.

I have a report that filters only Texas accounts, and then has two groups that break it into business or no business. I also created a formula field for each grouping that divides that row count by the Texas Grand Total row count to get a percentage.

The thing is I'm trying to get the percentage of just the Texas accounts with business on a dashboard metric.

I can only seem to get the row counts to show up in the metric and note either of the summary formula fields. Is there any other clever ways to get the percentage of just one of the groups on a metric?

Answer (score 1):

I managed this by making sure the summary formula was set to display "Grand Total Only". In order for it to show up in a metric it needs to be on the grand summary row, not just the "specific groups" section.

The formula I ended up using for the percent didn't actually use the grouping, but it used the field that was used to make the grouping. The field was a formula field on the account that was 1 if it has business and 0 if it didn't. (This could also have been done within the report formula, but we already had it so I just used that). And the denominator was just the row count, because the report already had all of the filters needed for that.
So `Account.Has_Business__c:SUM/PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, GRAND_SUMMARY)`